# Ubuntu w/ LibreOffice on a Tablet PC - does it have inking capabilities?

Tags: libreoffice

Ubuntu w/ LibreOffice on a Tablet PC - does it have inking capabilities?

i use mt Tablet PC (TPC) solely for it's inking capabilities. Micro$oft Word actually has inking capabilties, so i use it all of the time. in looking to get away from M$, does anyone know if LibreOffice, and specifically Writer, is ink-able? this way i can open my Word Documents in Writer and continue to ink on them.

thanks for any info!

Answer (score 0):

Libreoffice 4.0 Adds capabilities of importing ink annotations on MS Word and RTF documents. But, it doesn't yet support the pen devices very well. So, ability to read your ink annotations on LO is certain. But, you might want to try out if you can add and edit ink annotations on your device on LO.

https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/4.0#Writer

Answer (score 0):

LibO-Version 2.0.4. does not show annotations for me.

I generated a DOCX file (Word 2016), and LibO didn't show any signs of the positioning-frames containing the annotations, nor the annotations themselves.

The ODCX file saved as DOC (2003 Word) provided at least the positioning-frames that contain the annotations, but still without them.

The files are not corrupt and the annotations were displayed in Word 97, 2003 and 2016, when I tested the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try LibreOffice 7.6. It is the newest version and many of the old problems have been corrected.